# Как правильно составить запрос к MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdo

Есть две таблицы: base_bill и base_poz
В base_bill поля:

```
id_b | date_bill | date_pay | name_b | stat_b | uid
```

В base_poz поля:

```
id_p | name_p | col_p | col_price | price_p | uid_p
```

Таблица base_bill хранит информацию о счетах, а в таблице base_poz хранится информация о позициях и суммах в счете. Привязка по полю uid_p=id_b.

Вопрос, как посчитать итоговую сумму (price_p) по каждому отдельному счету?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT base_bill.id_b, SUM(base_poz.price_p) as summa FROM base_bill INNER JOIN base_poz ON base_poz.uid_p = base_bill.id_b WHERE base_bill = ID GROUP BY base_bill.id_b
```

Comment: `group by base_bill.id_b` забыли

Comment: Спасибо. Обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается все просто было =)